# My code only works if blocks are in a certain order

Tags: javascript, loops, nested-loops, nested-if

I am writing a function in Javascript to check if the string argument has balanced brackets.

Balanced brackets:

- A string is considered balanced if it has as many opening brackets of a given type as it has closing brackets of that same type.
- No bracket can be left unmatched. A closing bracket also cannot match a corresponding opening bracket that comes after it.
- Brackets also cannot overlap each other.

The function iterates over the given string and checks each bracket type, (), [], {}, to see if there is a correct pair.
The method is to iterate over the string to check for an opening bracket and then if found, iterate over the rest of the string for the corresponding closing bracket, then remove the pair. Each of the code blocks do this with each different bracket type. At the end, if there are any stray closing or opening brackets, it will return false, otherwise it will return true.

After running my code tested on a string of balanced brackets, **({[]})**, I've found it works only if I check the brackets in the order they appear in the string. I'm not sure why the order of these blocks affect how it works. Connecting the conditionals with "else if" instead of just "if" does not have any affect.

```
function hasBalancedBrackets(string) {
    var stringArray = string.split('');
        
    for (var i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
        
        if (stringArray[i] === '(') {
            for (var j = i+1; j < stringArray.length; j++) {
                if (stringArray[j] === ')') {
                    stringArray.splice(i, 1);
                    stringArray.splice(stringArray.indexOf(')'), 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (stringArray[i] === '{') {
            for (var l = i+1; l < stringArray.length; l++) {
                if (stringArray[l] === '}') {
                    stringArray.splice(i, 1);
                    stringArray.splice(stringArray.indexOf('}'), 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (stringArray[i] === '[') {
            for (var k = i+1; k < stringArray.length; k++) {
                if (stringArray[k] === ']') {
                    stringArray.splice(i, 1);
                    stringArray.splice(stringArray.indexOf(']'), 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    console.log('stringArray:', stringArray); // to check that all the bracket pairs have been removed
    if (stringArray.indexOf('(') === -1 && stringArray.indexOf('[') === -1 && stringArray.indexOf('{') === -1 && stringArray.indexOf(')') === -1 && stringArray.indexOf(']') === -1 && stringArray.indexOf('}') === -1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

// Assertion functions and test suite

function assertEqual(actual, expected, testName) {
    if (actual === expected) {
        console.log(`Passed [${testName}]`);
    } else {
        console.log(`FAILED [${testName}] Expected "${expected}", but got "${actual}"`);
    }
}

// tests

// input has balanced brackets, part 2
var actual4 = hasBalancedBrackets('({[]})');
assertEqual(actual4, true, 'Returns true when input string has balanced brackets');
```

Ordering of the code blocks and affect on the function:

- {}, (), [] - fails, does not find the braces {}
- {}, [], () - fails, does not find the braces {}
- [], {}, () - fails, does not find the braces {}
- [], (), {} - fails, does not find the square brackets []
- (), [], {} - fails, does not find the square brackets []
- (), {}, [] - passes

Comment: This isn't the best way to do it. Use a stack. Push the opening brackets on the stack. When you see a closing bracket, pop the top element of the stack and check if it matches the current closing bracket.

Comment: If the stack is empty when you try to pop you have an extra closing bracket. If it's not empty when you get to the end, you have extra opening brackets.

Comment: Your method will only work if you keep removing inner brackets until all are gone. I.e. you would need to wrap the three for loops in a while loop that keeps going until it's done. Do some basic debugging and add `console.log(stringArray)` in between your loops to see what's happening.

Comment: What @Barmar is describing is a [pushdown automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton) which will in fact do what you want effectively. Just FYI, if you want to do some more research on that topic.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for that suggestion, but I'm not familiar with stacks or concerned with the /best/ way to do this right now. I'm just trying to see if this method will work and  what's going on with it right now to make it not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your outermost `for` block increments index i but the code inside removes elements from the array. So if the inner code removes anything from the array, when the outer loop is run again, it skips the new first element.

{}()[]

first run of outer loop removes {} and []

now stringArray is ()

second run of outer loop now starts at index 1, which is ), so it doesn't find the pair.

Comment: Ah, yes, thank you, this was the issue! I added lines to decrement i each time a bracket was removed and that fixed it. Thanks so much!